# Issue with image scrape and backups

Tags: php, html, database, rows

My problem:

I have a script that scrapes a site for info (with permission).
The results may result in an empty answer, a link, or with the frase "N/A".

If the result is empty or is N/A, I want the script to print intern link to my no_image.png. But if my database row "poster" does have a link in it I'd want to show that instead of the scrape-result.

If both the scrape and my row poster is empty och my scrape is N/An I'd like to show no_image.png..

Here comes a snippet of the code... and yes.. I know it's total noob written:

```
if (!empty($row["poster"])){
    tr("Poster", "<object data='".$row["poster"]."height='250' width='200' align='left''title='object2' ><img src='".$image_dir."no_image.png'height='250' width='200' align='left' title='2'></object>", 1);

     }  else {
           tr("Poster", "<object data='".$row["scrape"]."'height='250' width='200' align='left' title='object1' ><img src='".$image_dir."no_image.png'height='250' width='200' align='left' title='1'></object>", 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values you mentioned are inside `$row['poster']`?

If so, you can compare it with both values you consider.

```
if ($row['poster'] === '' || $row['poster'] === 'N/A') {
    tr('Poster', '<object data="' . $row["poster"] . '" height="250" ' .
            'width="200" align="left" title="object2">' . 
            '<img src="' . $image_dir . '/no_image.png" height="250" ' . 
            'width="200" align="left" title="2"></object>', 1);
} else {
    tr('Poster', '<object data="' . $row["poster"] . '" height="250" ' .
            'width="200" align="left" title="object2">' . 
            '<img src="' . $image_dir . '/' . $row["poster"] . '" height="250" ' . 
            'width="200" align="left" title="2"></object>', 1);
}
```

I don't know what `tr` function is, but if you are sure you are using it in correct format, then the above code should do that. And you need to make sure that `$image_dir` is correct.

Comment: this  does seem to work :D i've tried it in some different wyas now and it seems to do the work! i'll mark this as accepted answer! thank you mate!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is something as simple as testing for N/A as well?

```
 if (!empty($row["poster"]) && $row["poster"]!='N/A'){
    tr("Poster", "<object data='".$row["poster"]."'height='250' width='200' align='left''title='object2' ><img src='".$image_dir."'no_image.png' height='250' width='200' align='left' title='2'></object>", 1);

     }  else {
           tr("Poster", "<object data='".$row["scrape"]."'height='250' width='200' align='left' title='object1' ><img src='".$image_dir."no_image.png'height='250' width='200' align='left' title='1'></object>", 1);
}// JavaScript Document
```

Comment: notice the syntax colour coding?

Comment: thanks, but that didn't do the trick :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the syntax errors I'm partially red coloured blind